# SSRS-2016 get HTTP Error 503 after server restart

Tags: ssrs-2016

I install and config SSRS-2016 on windows server-2012 and IIS-7 everything is good until i restart server or power failure then i get HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.i find a alternative solution to solve this.when i change web portal URL and apply changes the problem disappear.how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 10 day nobody answer my question.but i find answer
just change SSRS-2016 service from automatic to automatic delay

Comment: Evidently no one else has had this issue. Luckily you posted the solution that you figured out in case anyone has the same issue in the future.